# How do I flush the cin buffer?

Tags: c++, cin, io-buffering

How do I clear the cin buffer in C++?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Possibly:

```
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

This would read in and ignore everything until `EOF`. (you can also supply a second argument which is the character to read until (ex: `'\n'` to ignore a single line).

Also: You probably want to do a: `std::cin.clear();` before this too to reset the stream state.

Comment: Clear before, rather than after, so the stream is put into a good state where it can operate on its buffer.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that for my case, I find the '\n' necessary. Otherwise subsequent "cin >>" doesn't work.

Comment: For me this halts until it finds at least as many characters as the argument (microsoft compiler)

Comment: @Nic - of course, this tells the code to ignore ALL characters until the amount specified. In the main example, it will ignore essentially until `EOF` (because `INT_MAX` is huge). 

As mentioned in the post, if you just want to ignore a single line, you need to specify an extra parameter of `'\n` to tell it you only want to ignore up to the end of the line.

Comment: If you do this the next time you call getline(cin, input) you can press a char followed by enter all day long it won't go through.

Comment: Because C++ file streams and C file streams don't share buffers. Each implementation does there own independent buffering using slightly different methodologies.

Answer (score 140):

I would prefer the C++ size constraints over the C versions:

```
// Ignore to the end of Stream
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())

// Ignore to the end of line
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

Comment: More importantly, the values might be different! (streamsize doesn't have to be int)

Comment: could you please cite an example where we need to ignore to the end of file because if I use `cin` and use the first statement above to flush the `cin` buffer, then it keeps prompting for input till I enter `EOF` by pressing `ctrl+d`?

Comment: @ajay: No. That is something you will need to decide. I am merely explaining what the above will do.

Answer (score 34):

```
cin.clear();
fflush(stdin);
```

This was the only thing that worked for me when reading from console. In every other case it would either read indefinitely due to lack of \n, or something would remain in the buffer.

EDIT:
I found out that the previous solution made things worse. THIS one however, works:

```
cin.getline(temp, STRLEN);
if (cin.fail()) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: yeah, don't use fflush on stdin _(or any stream that's opened for reading for that matter)_ , it's undefined behavior

Answer (score 18):

I have found two solutions to this.

The first, and simplest, is to use `std::getline()` for example:

```
std::getline(std::cin, yourString);
```

... that will discard the input stream when it gets to a new-line. Read more about this function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline).

Another option that directly discards the stream is this...

```
#include <limits>
// Possibly some other code here
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 12):

```
int i;
  cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";

  // cin >> i; leaves '\n' among possible other junk in the buffer. 
  // '\n' also happens to be the default delim character for getline() below.
  cin >> i; 
  if (cin.fail()) 
  {
    cout << "\ncin failed - substituting: i=1;\n\n";
    i = 1;
  }
  cin.clear(); cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n'); 

  cout << "The value you entered is: " << i << " and its double is " << i*2 << ".\n\n";

  string myString;
  cout << "What's your full name? (spaces inclded) \n";
  getline (cin, myString);
  cout << "\nHello '" << myString << "'.\n\n\n";
```

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
```

Comment: the streambuf's in_avail() function is unreliable, and many implementations just return zero. See: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/509337/vc-8-9-sstream-basic-streambuf-sputc-sputn-dont-increment-gcount gnu's libc++ is similar

Answer (score 5):

Another possible (manual) solution is

```
cin.clear();
while (cin.get() != '\n') 
{
    continue;
}
```

I cannot use fflush or cin.flush() with CLion so this came handy.

Comment: infinite loop for me.

Comment: It is working only if there is end of line, otherwise infinite loop

Answer (score 4):

I prefer:

```
cin.clear();
fflush(stdin);
```

There's an example where cin.ignore just doesn't cut it, but I can't think of it at the moment. It was a while ago when I needed to use it (with Mingw).

However, fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior according to the standard. fflush() is only meant for output streams. fflush(stdin) only seems to work as expected on Windows (with GCC and MS compilers at least) [as an extension to the C standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz(v=vs.71).aspx).

So, if you use it, your code isn't going to be portable.

See [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Also, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=9129c7bd6e5c8fd67eb332126b59b54c&p=452568&postcount=1 for an alternative.

Comment: fflush(stdin); is Undefined Behavior (in the C programming language), explicitly stated so in 7.18.5.2/2

Comment: +1 for supplying a valid, working kludge. Some people have jobs others have standards.

Comment: @Mikhail: Your job should include writing standard compliant code.  I will make sure to avoid using anything you have written in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way:

```
cin.seekg(0,ios::end);
cin.clear();
```

It just positions the cin pointer at the end of the stdin stream and cin.clear() clears all error flags such as the EOF flag.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me. I have used for loop with getline().

```
cin.ignore()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
cin.flush();
```

On some systems it's not available and then you can use:

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

Comment: why manually write a loop when you can tell ignore the read INT_MAX chars until it reaches EOF (the default value of the second param).

Comment: Gunnar, might be better to edit your post to reflect this, just in case.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `flush` method is for output only, and deals with already written characters.

Comment: cin.flush(): `basic_istream<char>' has no member named 'flush'`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio_ext.h>
```

and then use function

```
__fpurge(stdin)
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin.get()` seems to flush it automatically oddly enough (probably not preferred though, since this is confusing and probably temperamental).

Answer (score -2):

fflush(stdin) − It is used to clear the input buffer memory. It is recommended to use before writing scanf statement.

fflush(stdout) − It is used for clearing the output buffer memory. It is recommended to use before printf statement.
The following should work:

cin.flush();
On some systems it's not available and then you can use:

cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
Both Windows and Linux define the behaviour of fflush() on an input stream,
and even define it the same way (miracle of miracles).
The POSIX, C and C++ standards for fflush() do not define the behaviour,
but none of them prevent a system from defining it.
If you're coding for maximum portability,  avoid fflush(stdin);
if you're coding for platforms that define the behaviour, use it — but be aware that it is not portable
portable code does not use fflush(stdin). Code that is tied to Microsoft's platform may use it and
it may work as expected, but beware of the portability issues.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/2752075) says `fflush(stdin)` is UB. I wouldn't recomment `fflush(stdout)` by default, and if you do use it, it should be after outputting stuff.