# How can I clear the input buffer in a c++ application?

Tags: c++, input

I make a lot of simple console c++ applications and one problem I am facing is the input buffer. I have tried cin.ignore and flush(), but they don't seem to be working for me.

If I have code such as:

```
cin >> char1;
cin >> char2;
```

and I press: 1 (space) 2 (Enter), with just one enter, the 1 is stored to char1 and the 2 is stored to char2.

Sorry if I am a little fuzzy on what I am asking. I will try to edit this question if people don't understand.

Comment: Would you want the `1` stored and the `2` (and the space) ignored?

Comment: Yes. I would want the space and the 2 ignored since it is storing the data to a char

Comment: @Ajay: You could try inputting to strings, then stripping out only the first char.

Comment: I could with string.at(#), but it gets messy with integers and other variables. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Actually I just tested it and the string is terminated with a space character so it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to read the whole line at once, then [std::string at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/) if you need the first char, or use an `isstringstream` if you need the first number.

```
char char1;
std::string input;

getline(std::cin, input);
if (!std::cin.good()) {
  // could not read a line from stdin, handle this condition
}

std::istringstream is(input);
is >> char1;
if (!is.good()) {
  // input was empty or started with whitespace, handle that
}
```

Wrap that in a function if you do it often. With the above, if you hit enter directly (no characters entered), or if you enter data starting with whitespace, `is` will be `!good()` so `char1` will *not* have been set.

Alternatively, after you've checked that `cin` is still good, you could simply:

```
if (input.empty()) {
  // empty line entered, deal with this
}
char1 = input.at(0);
```

With that, if the string is non-empty, `char1` will be set to the first `char` if `input`, whatever that is (including whitespace).

Note that:

```
is >> char1;
```

will only read the first char, not the first number (same with the `input.at()` version). So if the input is `123 qze`, `char1` will receive `'1'` (0x31 if ASCII), not the value 123. Not sure if that is what you want or not. If it's not what you want, read to an `int` variable, and cast properly afterwards.

Comment: Well, thank you for all your input. You have all been extremely helpful and educational. I think I have enough methods here to say my question is answered. I will try these out in the morning.

Comment: It reads one line, and takes the first `char` from it. That's all. If the line is empty, `char1` will be left untouched, so you need to check `is.good()`. If the line only has spaces, `char1` will also be left untouched and `is.good()` will be false.

Comment: Sounds like what I need. Thanks, I'll mark it as the answer for now.

Answer (score 4):

look this:

```
int a,b;
cin>>a;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
cin>>b;
```

this would read in and ignore everything until '\n' to ignore a single line

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first character from the line, read the entire line and then split it up:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
char1 = s[0]; // this reads the lead character
```

If you want the first non-whitespace character, use an istringstream and grab a character:

```
#include <sstream>
std::istringstream iss(s);
iss >> char1;
```

The "C" way of doing it on linux requires termios and looks something like this:

```
#include <termios.h>

struct termios t;
tcgetattr(0, &t); 
t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; // unbuffered
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t); // make the change now
char1=getchar()
char2=getchar()
```

now if you try typing "12" then char1 = '1' and char2='2'

Comment: But this doesn't flush the input buffer. It just grabs the first character the the code after this is still subject to my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the first character when you type it?  If so, there's a C-way to do it using getchar.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get input from the keyboard in a way that if I type: 232 253 and then press enter, the 253 isn't kept in the input buffer. Because what is happening is that a space like that is causing the second half of text to be stored to the next variable I "cin". Note: there is a space between 232 and 253 above.

Comment: Well, thank you for all your input. You have all been extremely helpful and educational. I think I have enough methods here to say my question is answered. I will try these out in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with cstdio, then:

```
rewind( stdin );
```

should do the job. Otherwise, I think your question was answered in [How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer).

Comment: Well, thank you for all your input. You have all been extremely helpful and educational. I think I have enough methods here to say my question is answered and I will try these out in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> char1;

cin >> char2;

fflush(stdin);
```

---

if user enters: `aaaaa bbbbb ccccc`

it will input `aaaaa into char1`

and put `bbbbb into char2`

the rest will be ignored