# several getchar calls

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, getchar

I have a VS 10 console application,which has to take two char inputs and make some processing based on their values.I wrote the following code:

```
char c1,c2;
printf("Ener c1:");
c1 = getChar();
//Some desicion is made based on c1
printf("Ener c2:");
c2 = getChar();
//Some desicion is made based on c2
```

Run it with :

```
Ener c1:y
Ener c2:S
```

After this execution the value of `c1` is `'y'` and the value of `c2` is `'\n'`
How can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a single char from cin, the user technically presses the character: 'y' then enter, or '\n'.

The \n is in the buffer, so you should flush the buffer after the first getchar to remove the \n.  Try using `cin.ignore();`

PS: I'd read this instead and rethink what you're doing:

[How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

When you entered 'y' and pressed enter, your application received 2 characters, it received 'y' and '\n' (the enter key. A simple solution would be to loop until you have another char than \n or EOF :

```
while ((c2 = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```