# getting console input for Cstrings

Tags: c++, c, string, cstring, c-strings

## note: this is in C++ but using C-style strings

hello SO,

I'm working on an assignment and I need to get input from the console and save it to a cstring.  Everything compiles fine, but when the program runs, it just skips over getting input from the user.  So it will output: "Enter string to be inserted: " then skip the cin.getline function, then execute the next command.

Here's my header files, the declaration of the cstring, and the line of code I'm having trouble with.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char tempCString[500] = {};

//...code snipit...

  cout << "Enter string to be inserted: " << endl;
  cin.getline(tempCString, 500, '\n'); //I've also tried cin.getline(tempCString, 500);

//...end code snipit...

  return 0;
}
```

note: I can't use "cin >> tempCString" becaues it will only get the input up to the first space, I need to get input from the console of everything up to the newline.

Thank you

Comment: If it's getting skipped, chances are that you have a new-line left in the input buffer from some previous reading.

Comment: how would I go about clearing the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing `cin`'s buffer before getting new input:

```
#include <limits>

cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
cout << "Enter string to be inserted: " << endl;
cin.getline(tempCString, sizeof(tempCString), '\n');
```

See [How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257091/245265)

Comment: thank you for reminding me of this, I had forgotten about it.

Comment: I had heard that cin and cin.getline() didn't play well together.  Now I know why they say that haha.  just needed to put cin.ignore(1000, 10) after each cin >>