# taking first string input and then ignoring the rest

Tags: c++, string, input, getline

I want the user to enter a string, double and a long, but the thing is after the first time, the string is kind of being ignored and left empty and prompting for the double directly.

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string name;
    double price;
    long serial;

    cout << "Enter the dvd's name: "; getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter the dvd's price (in $): "; cin >> price;
    cout << "Enter the dvd's serial number: "; cin >> serial;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the dvd's name: "; getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter the dvd's price (in $): "; cin >> price;
    cout << "Enter the dvd's serial number: "; cin >> serial;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: the console of the code]

as you can see the first time, i can enter a string the second time just sends me directly to the double, and even if i ignored the missing string, and put a double and then a long, it will print name as empty string.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can try [flushing `cin`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer) before calling `getline` again

Comment: This is such a common problem. I'm sure it's been asked many times on here already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use istringstream in such cases (as shown below). But a better solution would be to use cin.ignore

```
#include <sstream>

int main () {
    string name,line;
    double price;
    long serial;

    cout << "Enter the dvd's name: "; getline(cin, line);
    name = line;
    cout << "Enter the dvd's price (in $): ";
    getline(cin,line);
    istringstream(line)>>price;
    cout << "Enter the dvd's serial number: ";
    getline(cin,line);
    istringstream(line)>>serial;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace (carriage returns or space) *after* the serial number is not retrieved, and the `getline` then picks it up.

**Edit:** As johnathon points out, `cin >> ws` does not work right in this case (I'm sure I used this like this before, though I can't find an example).

**Tested Solution:** Instead, adding this after the serial number will get the carriage return (and any other whitespace) out of the stream so that it is ready for the next DVD name.

```
string dummy;
getline(cin, dummy);
```

Comment: it's not the whitespace that's getting him it's the carrage returns

Comment: Those are whitepspace too. the `ws` manipulator will take in any whitepsace, which includes spaces, tabs, newlines, and carriage returns.

Comment: just to note, cin >> ws; prevents his code from advancing beyond that point, cin.ignore(2,'\n') works though.