# Why doesn't std::getline block?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, objective-c++, getline

I have this code in an Objective-C class (in an Objective-C++ file):

```
+(NSString *)readString
{
    string res;
    std::getline(cin, res);
    return [NSString stringWithCString:res.c_str() encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

When I run it, I get a zero-length string, Every time. Never given the chance to type at the command line. Nothing. When I copy this code verbatim into `main()`, it works. I have ARC on under Build Settings. I have no clue what it going on. OSX 10.7.4, Xcode 4.3.2.

It *is* a console application.

Comment: Have you tried `std::cin` just in case `cin` got shadowed?

Comment: Is there a newline waiting in the buffer?

Comment: Does `cin` have any error flags set on it?

Comment: It means there is input waiting to be read on the input. You can empty the input: [cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())](http://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/14065)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: No. I never even get a chance to type. It just plods along without allowing me to type.

Comment: @Linuxios so, you haven't ever entered any input for the entire lifetime of the program? (Not just counting in the function call)

Comment: @LokiAstari: No dice. Just makes me have to hit enter twice for the input that does work.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I have. I enter a string, followed by a newline twice. Then I enter an int followed by a newline, float followed by a newline, and then the problem occurs. There are strings being printed between all of the input operations.

Comment: @LokiAstari: That did work! Post as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, mysterious I/O behavior is only mysterious because you don't do error checking.

Comment: @Linuxios the output doesn't matter. When you enter a number, the digits of the number are read, _and the newline is not read_. So there's a newline waiting to be read. When you use `getline`, it reads the newline and immediately returns, not allowing you to enter any input because it's already found the end of the line.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I know. Why do you think that socket IO is so ugly? But errors writing to stdout? I hope that never happens...

Comment: @Hurkyl no, this is the classic "reading a string after a number" problem.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Exactly. Thank you so much. I was beating my head on the keyboard over this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means there is input waiting to be read on the input. You can empty the input:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();
std::getline(cin, res);
```

If this is happening it means you did not read all the data off the input stream in a previous read. The above code will trash any user input before trying to read more.

This probably means that you are mixing `operator>>` with `std::getline()` for reading user input. You should probably pick one technique and use that (std::getline()) throughout your application ( you can mix them you just have to be more careful and remove the '\n' after using operator>> to make sure any subsequent std::getline() is not confused..

If you want to read a number read the line then parse the number out of the line:

```
std::getline(cin, line);
std::stringstream  linestream(line);

linestream >> value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
cin.ignore();
```

or use

```
cin.clear();
cin.sync();
```

before using `getline()`