# why does adding a space makes the compiler go into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, struct

Case 3 is an option to add a book to the structure. As long as books with titles without spaces are added, they are ok, whenever I try to put a name that has a space in it, the compiler goes crazy, sorta like what it would do if you execute an infinite loop. Why and what is the solution?

```
struct bookStruct
{
    string bookTitle;
    int bookPageN;
    int bookReview;
    float bookPrice;
};

const int MAX_BOOKS=10;



case 3:
        {
            for(int i=0;i<MAX_BOOKS;i++)
            {
                if(books[i].bookTitle=="\0")
                {
                cout << "\nPlease Enter the Title: ";
                cin >> books[i].bookTitle ;
                cout << "\nPlease Enter Total Number of Pages: ";
                cin >> books[i].bookPageN ;
                cout << "\nPlease Enter Rating (stars): ";
                cin >> books[i].bookReview ;
                cout << "\nPlease Enter Price: ";
                cin >> books[i].bookPrice;
                cout << "\n\nBook Added.\n\n";
                break;
                }
            }break;

        }
```

Comment: You've posted 3 questions regarding your code. Don't you think you should figure this stuff out on your own via searching like google or using a debugger?

Comment: The *compiler* doesn't do anything unusual.  It is your program that the compiler created on your behalf that gets stuck.

Comment: @Rapptz I have trying that all day, with no luck and no valid answers from here either.

Comment: If you don't think none of the answers given to your questions are valid, or rather "acceptable", then you should not mark them as accepted.

Comment: By the way, comparing with `"\0"` is a bit redundant as `""` contains one `'\0'` character, and the former contains two. Even better is `if (books[i].bookTitle.empty())`.

Comment: @chris I think the problem is in the loop, rather than the comparison.

Comment: The comparison's fine. I was merely commenting on the redundancy and suggesting the ideal way of checking whether a string is empty.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14312884/14065

Answer (score 4):

The input operator `>>` stops at space when reading strings.
What you want to use is [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
cout << "\nPlease Enter the Title: ";
std::getline(std::cin, books[i].bookTitle);
```

The input operator `>>` when reading a number will also stop at a space or newline (leaving them on the input stream). Thus when you wrap around to the next book there is still a '\n' character on the input stream. So for numbers you also need to use std::getline(). But in this case you need to convert the value to an integer.

```
cout << "\nPlease Enter Total Number of Pages: ";
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::stringstream linestream(line);
linestream >> books[i].bookPageN ;
```

Comment: any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju Read my answer again.

Comment: why this doesnt work and still is putting my code through an infinite loop when I use a space.

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju: The reason it goes into an infinite loop is the stream becomes bad and there is a bug in some other part of your code that you have not shown. To fix the local problem see the updated answer.

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju: But you are doing it wrong. You should be defining an input operator for the class `bookStruct`.