# Trouble with the correct format of displaying text string from the file in C++

Tags: c++, string, format, numbers, ifstream

I have a problem with the correct formatting of text (a string of numbers), after retrieving it from a file. My goal is to display it in the console format:

```
number number number number ... number
```

but it displays in form, where each of the number is displayed in a separate line e.g.:

```
6
928
81
4
496
3
8
922
0
5
39
731
53
```

The desired format:

```
6 928 81 4 496 3 8
922 0 5 39 731 53
```

etc.

Example Input File (`start.txt`) looks as follows :

```
6 928 81 4 496 3 8
922 0 5 39 731 53
6 3 48 9 15 971 48
631 30 7 04 31 96
18 78 409 30 55 6
0 75 8 4 0 9 73 61 3
8 36 40 21 05 825
66 4 7 9 05 96 3
6 43 5 3 39 3 07
77 0 2 76 7 8 3 5
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <random>
#include <chrono> 
#include <cmath> 
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    {
        const string OSOBNIKI{ "start.txt" };

        ifstream file(OSOBNIKI);
        if (file)
        {
            string chromosom;

            while (file>> chromosom)
                cout << chromosom << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have been trying it with multiple cout's. But I have not found the right solution to format it as in original file. It would be best to use some kind of loop as I guess.

Comment: I suggest you look into [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for reading lines. And [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) if you need to extract the values from each line.

Comment: I added [ while (getline(file, chromosom)) ] and applied it to the cout and got the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to expand on that, you can answer your own question (for the next guy).

Comment: I found your presentation very confusing to read. I took a guess as to what you meant. Did my edit stick to your intent?

Comment: It seems like your question is along the same lines as [why does adding a space makes the compiler go into an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14700181) although the setup is different.

Comment: Yes JaMiT, thank you for the edit. It is now more clear to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Printing `std::endl` writes a new line to the output.  That is why each number is being printed out on its own line.

You want to print a new line only when you encounter a new line in the input, but `operator>>` ignores leading whitespace, including new lines.  So, your current code has no way to know when a new line is encountered.

To do what you want, use `std::getline()` to read the file line-by-line, and use `std::istringstream` to read the numbers from each line.

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const string OSOBNIKI{ "start.txt" };

    ifstream file(OSOBNIKI);
    string line;
    int chromosom;

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> chromosom) {
            cout << chromosom << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```