# Why does the compiler executes an infinite loop upon having space as a Character?

Tags: c++, database, struct, switch-statement, do-while

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int optionChosen=0;

struct bookStruct
{
    string bookTitle;
    int bookPageN;
    int bookReview;
    float bookPrice;
};

const int MAX_BOOKS=10;

int main()
{
    bookStruct books[10]={};


    do
    {
        cout << "Please Select an Option from the Menu:\n\n" << endl;
        cout << "1. Display List of Books.\n" << "2. Find Book.\n" << "3. Add New Book.\n";
        cout << "4. Delete Book.\n"<<"5. Save List to File.\n"<<"6. Load List from File.\n";
        cout << "7. Sort List.\n"<<"8. Exit.\n\n";
        cin >> optionChosen;
        switch(optionChosen)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                for (int i=0;i<MAX_BOOKS;i++)
                {
                    if(books[i].bookTitle!="\0")
                    {
                    cout << "Book Title: " << books[i].bookTitle << endl;
                    cout << "Total Pages: " << books[i].bookPageN << endl;
                    cout << "Book Review: " << books[i].bookReview << endl;
                    cout << "Book Price: " << books[i].bookPrice<< "\n\n" << endl;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        case 2:
        {

        }
        case 3:
        {
            for(int i=0;i<MAX_BOOKS;i++)
            {
                if(books[i].bookTitle=="\0")
                {
                cout << "\nPlease Enter the Title: ";
                cin >> books[i].bookTitle ;
                cout << "\nPlease Enter Total Number of Pages: ";
                cin >> books[i].bookPageN ;
                cout << "\nPlease Enter Rating (stars): ";
                cin >> books[i].bookReview ;
                cout << "\nPlease Enter Price: ";
                cin >> books[i].bookPrice;
                cout << "\n\nBook Added.\n\n";
                break;
                }
            }break;

        }
        case 4:
        {

        }
        case 5:
        {

        }
        case 6:
        {

        }
        case 7:
        {

        }
        default:
        {
            if(optionChosen!=8)
            {
                cout << "Wrong Input Chosen\n";
                break;
            }
        }

        }



    }
    while(optionChosen<=8);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. 2 Question.....1. When I press anything that is not a number (a,b,c,abc) as an option, the program executes an infinite loop (maybe) and doesnt stop. Q#2.  When I am adding a book, if I use space, the code does the same thing (executes possible infinite loop) and never stops. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: BTW, the cases that are Empty will be used later, just telling you so you dont wonder what they are for.

Comment: Check the result of any input operation you do.

Comment: @chris I didnt quite get what you said?

Comment: The return value can be used to check for success. These might help: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Comment: Side note: compiler does not "execute infinite loop" - it compile your code into executable and than you run it...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am saying the program enters an infinite loop.

Comment: [Here is a duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)

Comment: Mokammel Hossain Sanju, I don't want to sound rude, but have you read your question/title?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh sorry, my bad, it should have been why does the compiler enters in an infinite loop. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is easy. When you `cin >> some_int;` and there's no `int` in the input stream, it simply fails and leaves the input stream in its current state.

That means the the next time you go back to get another `int`, it will *still* have the non-integer ready for reading.

Comment: ok, I get what you are saying so this is not a used error rather a deadlock were nothing can be done with the basic operations so the used must input an Integer, am I right?

Comment: ok, I get what you are saying so this is not a used error rather a deadlock were nothing can be done with the basic operations so the used must input an Integer, am I right?

Comment: @Mokammel, it's not really deadlock, all that happens is that the input stream containing `a`, and the int variable you're trying to `>>` to, are left untouched. When you get round to `>>`ing to a string, it will pick the `a` up. More than likely it seems like an infinite loop but it's really a sequence issue.

Answer (score 0):

As paxdiablo mentioned, the non-integer inputs are still in the input stream. You need to call cin.ignore() to extract and discard the invalid characters.