# Do-while endlessly looping cout, ignores cin

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, do-while

This program prints a specified amount of numbers within a specified range. However, when I enter a character, it just endlessly loops whichever do-while loop I do it in. E.g: If I enter a character in "Enter maximum number" cin, it just spams "Enter maximum number" endlessly, it just skips the cin and loops the cout (same goes for the other 2 do-whiles. Anyone know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int roll(int mini, int maxi)
{
        int v = maxi - mini;
        int x  = mini + (rand() % (v+1));
        return x;

}
void caller()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    do {
    cout << "Enter minimum number" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> a;
    } while (cin.fail());

    do {
    cout << "Enter maximum number" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> b;
    } while (cin.fail() || a > b);

    do {
    cout << "How many rolls?" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> c;
    } while (cin.fail());

    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    cout << roll(a, b) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    caller();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never actually extract the character. It just sits there for next time you try to read something.

Comment: I'm still a beginner, what do you mean by extract? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Since you didn't actually read it, it's still in the stream, so next time you try to read anything, it will be the first thing read, which causes the problem again. Use `ignore` or something to discard the unreadable (at least for an `int`) characters.

Comment: Ignore only helps if I put a character once. If I do it a 2nd time, it just does the loop again.

Comment: Hint: Ignore more than one character. In fact, for keyboard input, just ignore all characters currently in the stream.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm still a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer not to use `istream::fail()` for loop control. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/78845) for a similar issue.

Instead, I rely upon the return value of `istream::operator >>`.

I also use the following function to reset the flags and clear the input on input stream:

```
void flush_stream(std::istream& stream)
{
    stream.clear();
    stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

See [How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer) for more on this.

So I'd code your input checks thus:

```
int get_valid_number(const std::string& prompt)
{
    int number = 0;

    bool valid = false;
    while (!valid)
    {
        std::cout << prompt << std::endl;
        if (std::cin >> number)
        {
            valid = true;
        }
        flush_stream(std::cin);
    }

    return number;
}
```

Hopefully the benefits of extracting this into a function are obvious. [See it run](http://ideone.com/R7EzgY).

Comment: While I do prefer this way, `operator bool()` and `operator void *()` use `fail()` to determine the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You could try doing something like

```
int a;
string trash;

do {
  cout << "Enter minimum number" << endl;
  cin >> a;

  if(cin.fail()){
    cin.clear();
    cin >> trash;
  }

} while (cin.fail());
```

This will remove any bad input from the cin stream by throwing it into the `trash` string.

This link may help you understand these `cin` functions a bit better.

http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~cs102/lectures/cinLecture.html