# Character input issue

Tags: c++, character

I have a simple code: If `ch` is `Y`, then the first `if` statement runs, if `N`, then the other, if anything else, then the `else` statement. But if I give more than one character, then it writes "wrong input" out many times. How can I solve this issue, so anything I write the `else` statement only runs once?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    char ch;


    do{
        cout << "Enter Y or N: ";
        cin >> ch;
        cout << endl;
        if(ch == 'Y'){
            cout << "You entered yes." << endl;
            running = false;
        } else if(ch == 'N'){
            cout << "You entered no." << endl;
            running = false;
        } else{
            cout << "Wrong input." << endl;
        }
    }while(running);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do-while endlessly looping cout, ignores cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907978/do-while-endlessly-looping-cout-ignores-cin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is clear the rest of the input stream to make sure on the next iteration you are waiting for new input and not reading input that was left in the buffer.  We can use `ignore` for that like

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You can either place it as the last line of the do loop so it clears the buffer for every case or you can add it to the last else statement.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working on the first try, but after this it accepts no input and the program crashes

Comment: It writes out wrong input once and after that it reacts to nothing.

Comment: @Ratonhnhaketon I forgot to add the delimiter.  Try the updated code.

Comment: Working. Thanks :)