# String input - first line being ignored

Tags: c++

Input problem in c++ and java if we input a string after an integer it will skip it go to the next statement.

```
    string name;
int age;
cout<<"Enter age";
cin>>age;
cout<<"Enter name";
getline(cin,name);



cout<<name;
cout<<age;

getch();
```

above code not taking name it skip this line.what aproblem with it......???

Comment: I don't see the java code here

Comment: I hope you didn't just tag java because it's a popular tag...

Comment: When you have line based input there is characters or new line after the first number you still haven't read, it doesn't disappear just because you asked for more data.

Comment: i tag it for java because same problem with java....

Answer (score 2):

When the integer value is read the [Enter] introduced to finish the line is still in the stream, and `getline(cin,name)` reads that [Enter].

To solve the problem, first [flush cin before getting the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer/257182#257182):

```
string name;
int age;
cout<<"Enter age";
cin>>age;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignores all enters
cout<<"Enter name";
getline(cin,name);

cout<<name;
cout<<age;

getch();
```

Comment: thanks xorguy for your help...

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer for C++ only, as only C++ code is present.

`std::getline` will consumes the newline character left over the  input stream by previous `operator >>`, and hence it returns.

A simple work around is to ignore all leftover characters on the line of input with 
`cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

before using `std::getline`

```
#include<limits>
// ....
string name;
int age;
cout<<"Enter age";
cin>>age;

cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cout<<"Enter name";
getline(cin,name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cin >> age;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Let's say the user enters the integer 5. This is what the input stream will look like:

> ```
> 5\n
> ...
> ```

<sub>Note that the above could vary. The user could enter an integer and subsequently a space character. Both are equally valid situations.</sub>

That is, the user enters the value and hits return to submit. `operator >>` is formatted so that the integer will be consumed, but once it finds a new line or whitespace extraction will cease. After the input operation, the new line should still be in the stream.

> ```
> \n
> ...
> ```

Now, let's see the content for `name`:

> ```
> \n
> "Bruce Wayne"\n
> ```

When `getline` executes, once it finds a new line in the stream it will stop searching for new input. The new line from the previous extraction was still in the stream, so the input was stopped immediately. Nothing was extracted!

Fortunately, we can use the `ignore` method to discard the new line from the stream:

```
std::cin >> age;
std::cin.ignore(); // ignore the next character

std::getline(std::cin, age);
```

By default, `std::cin.ignore` will discard the next character from the stream when given 0 arguments.

Here is a **[live example](http://ideone.com/jmjzWy)**.