# How to get part of a string to one variable and everything else to another variable in c++

Tags: c++

my text is something like this

55`<space>`The User Input Sentence;

i got the 55 out via the code below and assigned that to a int variable via atoi

```
std::string stringKey = userInput.substr(0, 2);
```

but how to get the rest of the string and assign it to a string variable ????the code below

this is the complete code (haven't finished it yet)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
//FUnction Prototypes
string encrypt(string, int);
string decrypt(string source, int key);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string source;
    string userInput;
    int key;
    int choice;
    cout << "To encode a message type 1, to decode a message type 2: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter the message to encode: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        std::string stringKey = userInput.substr(0, 2);
        key = atoi(stringKey.c_str());
        std::string source = userInput.substr(3);
        encrypt(source, key);

    }


        /*decrypt(source, key);

    cout << "Source: ";
    getline(cin, source);

    cout << "Key: ";
    cin >> key;

    cout << "Encrypted: " << decrypt(source, key) << endl;*/
    system("pause");
}

string encrypt(string source, int key)
{
    string Crypted = source;

    for (int Current = 0; Current < source.length(); Current++)
        Crypted[Current] = ((Crypted[Current] + key) - 32) % 95 + 32;
        return Crypted;
}

string decrypt(string source, int key)
{
    string Crypted = source;

    for (int Current = 0; Current < source.length(); Current++)
        Crypted[Current] = ((Crypted[Current] - key) - 32 + 3 * 95) % 95 + 32;
    return Crypted;
}
```

Comment: check out `std::string substr` method

Comment: `std::regex` should do the job

Comment: taocap's method gives me the same out of range memory error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way as you got first part. Check out [`std::string substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

```
string second = userInput.substr(3);
```

----------------EDIT------------------

If you give `55<space>The User Input Sentence` as input, only first string will be read.
Use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) method to read entire input including spaces

Comment: yeah i did that and the program gives me this error Unhandled exception at 0x769DC41F in ASCII Cipher.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0019F638.

Comment: This probably means `userInput` has less number of characters

Comment: the user input is supposed to be the key space and the encrypting or decrypting message i cannot predict the length of the user message. in this case what should i do ??

Comment: You just need to know the length of key. Pass `(length+1)` to second `substr` call. This is the offset where your message starts

Comment: I meant read the entire line with spaces, so you can split them later.Edited my reply

Comment: like this getline (cin, userInput);

Comment: same error i guess Unhandled exception at 0x769DC41F in ASCII Cipher.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0029F854.

Comment: funny it keeps on giving me memory errors im using visual studio 2013 maybe thats the reason

Comment: try printing `userInput` after you read. Check if its same as you entered

Comment: it just bold this std::string source = userInput.substr(3); and gives the memory error message.

Comment: yep its the same as i typed

Comment: i entered 55 Hello World.

Comment: and also if i use get line the c++ wont even let me type anything it will give me the memory error, but if i use the cin command i can atleast type the user input

Comment: if i just use two cin statements for key and the text my code works perfectly it will encode and decode without a problem

Comment: Once you enter choice, it consumes only `int` not the enter you pressed. Add `cin.ignore();` inside the `if` block. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)