# Clean istream when input is not correct

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, istream

I am looking through the `istream` class and I don't see a method that cleans completely the buffer and sets the input to be ready for a next "clean" input.

I defined the extraction operator for my class, and in my main program I ask the user for an input, like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        cout << "Enter input: ";
        MyClass c;
        cin >> c;
        return c;
    } catch(const MyException& e) {
        cerr << "Error\n";
    }
}
```

If I enter an unexpected incorrect input I am trapped in an infinite loop.

In my overriden extractin method I control when the input is not correct and the exception is thrown, all this is ok. I just want to also clean the `istream` object so I prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: I really don't like the infinite while loop design, but possibly related to reset the stream: http://stackoverflow.com/q/257091/1938163

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the inserters/extrators for your classes shouldn't throw exceptions. IOStreams were designed not to throw exceptions by default and to remain consistent I would recommend that you not throw custom exceptions from your I/O operators.

As Dieter said, you're better off setting the [`std::ios_base::failbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) flag in the stream state instead of throwing. You can do this using the [`setstate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) method. Once you do that, you can check for a valid extraction with an `if()` statement. To answer your question, once you determine if the input is invalid, you clear the stream state, and clear the buffer for new input by calling [`ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) discard the rest of the characters:

```c++
while (std::cout << "Enter input: ")
{  
    X x;
    if (!(std::cin >> x))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid. Try again.\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        continue; // or break if needed
    }
    // handle good input and break if needed
}
```

Comment: These methods dont throw exceptions, the constructor does, it is called in the extraction method. The clear and ignore methods worked for me, that's the answer I was looking for, however I am calling them inside the extraction method, not outside of it. The responsible of cleaning the buffer should be the programmer's, not the user's.

Comment: @dabadaba If the constructor throws an exception within the extractor, then it is as if the extractor itself is throwing an exception. You should still wrap the constructor within a `try catch` block and set `failbit` in the stream as I've said. Also, I don't 100% agree that cleanup should be the programmers job. For example, the standard streams do not clean up invalid input. Moreover, if you're going to `clear()` the stream state when invalid input is present, how will the user ever know if he entered in invalid input in the first place?

Comment: @dabadaba I suppose you can cache the stream state, do the cleanup, and then reset the stream state in the stream. That would be good however.

Comment: he will know that he entered an invalid input because an exception is thrown, even though you say that these methods should not throw any exceptions