# QTextStream stdin readline not pausing for input

Tags: c++, qt4, qtextstream

Here is a very simple application to illustrate the problem I am having.

```
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    QTextStream cin(stdin);
    QTextStream cout(stdout);

    QString test;

    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cout.flush();
    cin >> test;

    cout << "Enter another value: ";
    cout.flush();

    test = cin.readLine();
    cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

I expect execution to pause and wait for input at `test = cin.readline();`, but it does not. If I remove `cin >> test;` then it pauses.

Why is this code behaving like this and how do I get behaviour I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>Probably the buffer still has a endline character `'\n'` that is accepted by `cin.readLine();` - try flushing it with `cin.flush()` before executing cin.readLine().</s>

---

This code is working:

```
QTextStream cin(stdin);
QTextStream cout(stdout);

QString test;

cout << "Enter a value: ";
cout.flush();
cin >> test;

cout << "Enter another value: ";
cout.flush();
cin.skipWhiteSpace(); //Important line!
test = cin.readLine();
cout << test;
return 0;
```

You just need to add `cin.skipWhiteSpace()` before `cin.readLine()`, as I said before the '\n' character is still in buffer and that method is getting rid of it.

Comment: I checked it on my computer, I am pretty sure that is about '\n' character, when you execute cin.readLine(); twice it is pausing.

Comment: You are correct. It seems you need to clear the buffer first. Here is something similar, but I'm not sure yet how to apply this is a QT context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer