# Why is my program getting a runtime error when I execute my code?

Tags: c++, return

This program is working without the loop, however when I implement the loop, I get a runtime error. I think it might have something to do with my cin.getline but I really have no idea :/ any help would be great thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


int main ()
{int ans, z;
z=1;
cout << "How many times would you like to execute this string program? " << endl;
cin >> ans;
while (z <= ans)
{  
    int x, i, y, v;
    string answer1, str3;
    string mystring, fname, lname;


    i=0;
    y=0;

    cout << "Please enter your first and last name: ";
    getline(cin, answer1);
    cout << endl;

    x=answer1.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << answer1[i] << endl;
        if (isspace(answer1[i])) 
        {
            y=i;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(80) << answer1;

    mystring = answer1;

    v=answer1.find(" ", 0);

    fname=mystring.substr(0, y);
    lname=mystring.substr(v, x);
    cout << "First name: " << fname << endl;
    cout << "Last name: " << lname << endl;

    mystring=lname+','+fname;

    cout << setw(80) << mystring;
    z++;    

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the error in more detail? Exactly what is the error you are getting?

Comment: This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact customer support.

Comment: What about stepping through with a decent debugger?!?

Comment: Answer should be here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer

Comment: [Set a breakpoint on `abort`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/08/10245330.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The error happens in this line:

```
lname=mystring.substr(v, x);
```

where `v` happens to have a very large value. So how does your program get there, and how does `v` get this value? `v` has value `std::string::npos`, which is an error code meaning, in this case, that the space you were looking for wasn't there. That this is the case has to do with the difference between *formatted* and *unformatted* input and the fact that you're mixing them.

*Formatted* input means treating an input stream as a stream of tokens. Leading whitespace -- all whitespace, whether space, tab, or newline -- is skipped, and where the token ends, there does the input. One example of formatted input is

```
cin >> ans;
```

For formatted input, everything that doesn't fit its pattern looks the same. Whether `std::istream::operator>>(int)` encounters a space, a tab, a newline, an `'a'` or a '`z'`, that's just the end of the token, and there it stops reading. For example, if you have

```
int x;
std::string s;
std::cin >> x >> s;
```

and feed it the input `123abc`, then `x` will have the value `123`, and `s` will be `"abc"`. Crucially, this means that if the user answers

```
cin >> ans;
```

with a number and newline, the encountered character after the number -- a newline -- **remains in the stream**.

*Unformatted* input, by contrast, means treating an input stream as a stream of characters. For unformatted input functions, whitespaces are just another character, and unless the unformatted input function defines a special meaning for them, it will treat them the same as any other character. An example of unformatted input is

```
getline(cin, answer1);
```

which is shorthand for

```
getline(cin, answer1, '\n'); // that is to say, the delimiter
                             // has a default value of '\n'
```

(just to make it clear that the newline character `'\n'` has a special meaning in this case). `getline`, used this way, will read from the stream until it encounters a newline.

And therein lies your problem. After the previous, *formatted* input function, there is stuff left in the stream that you don't care about. It is probably just a newline (although if the user provided `123abc`, it will be `abc\n`), in which case getline will give you an empty string -- there's an empty line in the stream, so what else can it do?

There are several ways to deal with this condition. One is to say

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This is essentially saying: ignore everything up to the next newline (the `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` is a very large number that `cin.ignore` treats as infinity). Another is

```
cin >> ws;
```

which says: "ignore everything up to the next non-whitespace character", although this will ignore leading spaces in the next line, and it will not ignore `abc` if the user provided `123abc`. In your case, I believe there is no reason to change gears from formatted input -- you don't want a line but first and last names. I suggest using

```
string fname, lname;
cin >> fname >> lname;
```

This will also eliminate the other error (that you're using an error code as string index), because you won't have to search for a space in the string that may not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
cin >> ans;
cin >> std::ws;
```

before the while loop. Also, check

```
v=answer1.find(" ", 0);
```

for
    std::npos

which is the value returned if find was unsuccessful.