# Warn user about incorrect int input

Tags: c++, int, cin

My program contains a simple input code:

```
int number;
std::cin >> number;
```

Of course, if user types 3.14, only "3" will be read. That's ok for the further code in general, but I want that kind of input to be marked as invalid and prompt user to try again with a proper integer.

Is there a way to check if anything was typed after the int?

Comment: Did you google at all? You can test the return value of your reading operation, example: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/21595/

Comment: `if (!(std::cin >> number) || !cin.eof())` but since we are talking about standard input, there isn't really an “end of input”.  Also note that we've had [a *very similar* question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28479888/1392132) just an hour ago.

Comment: The formatted input functions of C++ are pretty useless for any situation where you want rigorous input validation. You can do it, but it gets really ugly. I almost always end up extracting delimited strings (like lines with `getline`) and then parsing them myself.

Comment: You could also assume the number is a float or double, and then find the floor/ceiling of that number.  If the floor/ceiling of it is not equivalent to the original, then it's not an int.

Comment: @5gon12eder, The `eof` check is redundant as `!(std::cin >> number)` will be true if it hit EOF. Anyway, input could be redirected, or the user could enter ctrl-D or whatever variant.

Comment: @chris Note that both checks are negated.  The conditional will evaluate to `false` unless there was a valid `int` input *and* this was all input there was.  It is true that the user can hit *C*-d or the like but it would be awkward if a program *mandated* that just to read an integer.  The wording about stdin and eof in my previous comment was unfortunate, though.

Comment: @5gon12eder, Right, I don't know why I treated that as not negated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that take the input as a string and then parse it.
For example :

```
string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

Write some function to check the input.
For example :  `'0'<=s[i]<='9'`

You could even use regex.

**Update:**
As *5gon12eder* said: You have `std::stoi` function for the same. It will convert the string to int if it is valid integer. Otherwise it throws an exception `invalid_argument`.

Comment: The standard library already has a function for this: [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: Agreed, but you never know what user is going to type. stoi converts string to int. But the input may not be an integer.

Comment: In which case `std::stoi` and friends will throw `std::invalid_argument` which you can `catch` and act upon appropriately. (NB: `stoi` != `atoi`)