# inserting a student's name and its ID and show them

Tags: c++

Here is my C++ code

student.h

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class student
{
public:
void setname ();
string getname ();

void setstudentid ();
int getstudentid ();

student ();


private:
string name;
int studentid;

};
```

student.cpp

```
#include "student.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

student::student ()
{
    setname ();

    setstudentid ();

cout << "Student's Name: " << getname () << endl;
cout << "Student's ID: " << getstudentid () << endl;
}

void student::setname ()
{
    string x;

    cout << "Enter student's name: ";
    getline (cin , x);


    name = x;
}

string student::getname ()
{
    return name;
}

void student::setstudentid ()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Enter student's code: ";
    cin >> x;

    studentid = x;
}

int student::getstudentid ()
{
    return studentid;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a;

    cout << "1- stundent's info" << endl
        << "2- list of courses" << endl
        << "3- PickUp a course" << endl
        << "Please enter an option: ";
        cin >> a;

    if (a == 1)
    {
        student x;
    }
}
```

The problem is in the picture below:

[image]

How can I print them separately with initialized variable?

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you really need all the stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: Don't include pictures but the text, unless a picture is the only reasonable description. Further, reduce your code to the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem. Typically, that doesn't involve any unnecessary output and replaces user input with constants.

Answer (score 1):

After `cin >> a`, `\n` is left in the input buffer which is consumed in `getline(cin,x)`.
Reset and flush `cin` buffer before reading input again.
[How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)