# char input, y/n reads all letters

Tags: c++, char, c++98

So here's my code:

```
 b:
        cout << "\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
            goto a;
        else if (ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
            goto c;
        else
            cout << "Invalid Answer!";
        goto b;
```

my problem is if I enter 2 or more letters, it reads all and throws "invalid answer!" and prints "do you want to continue (y/n)" as many as the letters i've input. like this one

```
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? asd
Invalid Answer!
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? Invalid Answer!
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? Invalid Answer!
Do you want to continue (Y/N)?
```

Comment: The terminal buffers input.

Comment: This is because your variable `ans` is a `char`. The `cin` stream has a buffer. When you input `asd`, all three letters go into the buffer. For a solution, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer

Comment: Avoid `goto` in preference of loop constructs.

Answer (score 0):

your code is reading each character and displaying a result for each character, I think reading it as a string and getting the first character will solve it but i would recommend using  [getch()](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch)

Comment: `getch()` - like `<conio.h>` is not standard C++.   It is an extension specific to some vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

to clear the input.
In your case, your code should become:

```
 b:
        cout << "\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
            goto a;
        else if (ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
            goto c;
        else
            cout << "Invalid Answer!";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
        goto b;
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`  As the standard stipulates that if the first parameter is exactly equal to `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()`, the "extract up to X characters" test is ignored (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore , http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/ ), this means it'll extract as many characters as it can until it extracts a newline, at which point it stops.  On any system that stores Enter as `\n`, this effectively discards everything that you typed before pressing Enter.