# C++ getline(); displays one below

Tags: c++, string, c++11, cin

I have a strange problem here. I'm getting 2 strings as input using the code below:

```
std::string input1, input2;
std::cout<<"Please enter name:";
std::getline(std::cin, input1);
std::cout<<"Address: ";
std::getline(std::cin,input2);
```

The issue I'm having is that instead of displaying one at a time, both display at once, so the output looks like this:

`Please enter name: Address:`

As a result neither string is getting any input.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: `std::cout>>"Please enter name:";`?! How did you get this to compile? It should be `<<`.

Comment: @AmiTavory oops copied it incorrectly

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Is there any other input going on prior to this? How are you launching the program?

Comment: @Angew there is no input prior to this. It is in main()

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer

Comment: Put the code snippet inside `main` so that readers can compile and run it. I'll bet that you'll see that it works just fine, and that the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using cin.ignore() before getline // ignores \n that has been left after user pressed enter key

Comment: That's done it, thanks

Comment: @JohnKressel This, however, means there *must* have been some prior input (contrary to what you said in comments). The input stream is empty at program startup.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
cin.ignore();
```

Because in loop it will ignore you required input as well. Use

```
cin>>ws;
```

Before getline.  ws means white space this will ignore white space in your program and the code will work fine.