# C++11 : cin doesn't wait for user input and ends the loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, tuples, cin

My program takes user data as a `tuple` and stores it into a `vector`. There is no limit to how many `tuple`s can be added and `vector` size changes with the adding of `tuple`s. The program asks the user if they want to add another `tuple`. If no, the loop exits.

My problem is, when the program was supposed to wait for 'yes' or 'no' input, it skipped the cin and exited the loop.

I have tried searching for solutions, tried clearing the buffer but I am back to square one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(vector<tuple<int, string, string, bool>> const & data)
{
    if (data.size() != 0)
    {
        for (auto row : data)
        {
            cout << get<0>(row) << ", " << get<1>(row) << ", " << get<2>(row)
                 << ", " << get<3>(row) << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nNO ENTRIES CURRENTLY!";
    }
}
int main()
{
    int id;
    char go;
    string name, filePath;
    bool flag = false;
    typedef tuple<int, string, string, bool> pData;
    vector<pData> pList;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a Pattern Call:" << endl;
        cin >> id >> name >> filePath >> flag;

        pList.push_back(make_tuple(id, name, filePath, flag));

        cout << "Do You wish to add another: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> go; //The control skips here and exits the loop.
    } while (go == 'y' || go == 'Y');

    print(pList);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to read line-by-line using `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hack which seems to work on my Linux Machine.

1. Add `cin.clear()` before `cin.ignore()`
2. Replace `cin.ignore()` with `cin.ignore(1)`

Part of your code should look as below:

```
    cout << "Do You wish to add another: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1);
    cin >> go; //The control skips here and exits the loop.
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The problem still continues.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
[How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)
Using cin is not that easy or safe if user input is not exactly what we want.