# how do i input another string in same data member for another object in c++?

Tags: c++, cin, fflush

//Program for displaying total salary of employees

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
[enter image description here][1]
    class employee
    {
    char ename[25];
    int emp_id, basic_sal;
    float da, hra, total;
    public:
        int input();
        int calculate();
        int output();
};

int main()
{
    employee e1;
    employee e2;
    employee e3;
    cout <<"\n Enter details of first employee\n";
    e1.input();
    e1.calculate();
    cout <<"\n Enter details of Seond employee\n";
    e2.input();
    //fflush(stdin);
    e2.calculate();
    cout <<"\n Enter details of Third employee\n";
    e3.input();
    //fflush(stdin);
    e3.calculate();
    e1.output();
    e2.output();
    e3.output();
    return 0;
}
int employee::input()
{
    cout <<"Enter the name of employee\n";
    cin.clear();
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.getline(ename, 49);
    cout <<"Enter employee id\n";
    cin >>emp_id;
    cout <<"Enter the basic salary\n";
    cin >>basic_sal;
    return 0;
}
int employee::calculate()
{
    int pda, phra;
    cout <<"Enter DA (percentage)\n";
    cin >>pda;
    cout <<"Enter HRA (Percentage)\n";
    cin >>phra;
    da = (basic_sal*pda)/100;
    hra = (basic_sal*phra)/100;
    total = basic_sal + da + hra;
    return 0;
}
int employee::output()
{
    cout <<"Name of Employee - " <<ename <<"\n" <<"Employee ID - ";
    cout <<emp_id <<"\n" <<"Basic Salary - " <<basic_sal <<"\n"; 
    cout <<"Da - " <<da <<"\n" <<"hra - " <<hra  << "\n"; 
    cout <<"Total Salary - " <<total <<"\n\n\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code for object e1 the input is fine but it skips variable "ename" for object "e2" and object "e3". I cleared buffer using "fflush(stdin);". What would be the problem?
I am using g++ compiler and geany editor.
There are no compilation errors in the code.

Comment: fflush is for output stream. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/34518907/8491726

Comment: The \n left by the cin is probably the issue after cin add std::cin.ignore()

Comment: Use std::string instead of char arrays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the details of each employee entered on new line? If so, you must use something like

```
cin >> ws;
```

at the beginning of `employee::input()` function. It will skip all whitespaces until a first non-whitespace character is found (which is left intact).

Now, the `cin >> phra` loads some number from `stdin` (I presume the last number on the line), but does not consume the newline character after it. Therefore, it is left there for the first `cin.getline()` call in `employee::input()`, which will read only this newline, so the `ename` will be empty.