# Can't clear cin. Stuck at input

Tags: c++, cin, input-buffer

When `cin` fails, it fails for ever. I.e. I can't read anything afterwards and `cin.fail()` always returns true, no matter how I try to clear it.

Minimal code to recreate:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int d;

    while (!(cin >> d)) // Loop until I get a valid integer
    {
        cin.ignore(9999, '\n');
        cin.clear();
    }

    cout << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With minimal input:

```
a<Enter>
```

I tried all C++ answers under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091), but none of them worked. Strangely enough, `fflush(stdin)` did a good job.

I use Dev-C++ as my IDE and replaced its packaged GCC with MinGW GCC 6.3.0 from SourceForge. The following arguments are supplied to `g++.exe` when compiling

```
-Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -s -O3 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

The same issue has also occurred with GCC 7.2.0 on my Ubuntu without the last two `-static` arguments.

---

As suggested in comments, swapping the order of `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` worked. What's the reason for that?

Comment: @Sahu I don't think so - he wants to keep looping until he gets a valid integer.

Comment: I believe your data "a" in your example is stored in d. Once that happens the getline doesn't retrieve any useful data. Hence `waste` never change value.

Comment: @iBug Get rid of the string stuff, and swap the order of  ignore and clear. I've got a blog article on this at https://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/simple-input-bullet-proofing-in-c/

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you explain why should I swap the order of `ignore` and `clear`?

Comment: @iBug Because if you don't clear the stream, it's still bad, so ignore will not work correctly.