# How to get string input n times?

Tags: c++, for-loop, getline

I have a C++ program. I want to get a number from the user (`t`) and force the user to enter line `t` times but the program's execution terminates after 1 iteration. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i=0; i< t; i++) {
        getline(cin, str);
        cout << str;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me why this happening and how to solve it? 
Thank you my friends.

Comment: Hmmm, it will iterate `t-1` times (`-1` because newline character is not consumed by `cin >> t;`), not 1 times. ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Aao7gTXm0bWdBCwG))

Comment: Try `cin >> t; cin.ignore();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter your first character (the times to repeat), a character is left in the `cin` buffer - newlines are not consumed by `cin >>`. As a result, `getline(cin, str)` reads this character and takes it as the first input, which then empties the buffer out and lets you enter the others.

[You can clear the buffer with `std::cin.ignore(1);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257098/7431860) to remove that trailing character - this lets your code run as anticipated. Why not just use `cin >> str`, though? That solves the problem and avoids a call to `getline`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    //clear one character out of buffer
    cin.ignore(1);

    //note that 1 is used for demonstration purposes
    //in development code, INT_MAX, numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),
    //or some other large number would be best, followed
    //by std::cin.clear()

    for (int i=0; i< t; i++) {
        cout << "input: ";
        //you could use cin >> str; instead of getline(cin, str);
        getline(cin, str);
        cout << "got: " << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/ProductiveCleanList)

Comment: Thanks. it works

Comment: @AliAbbasifard `ignore(1)` works when the user is nice and doesn't enter anything more on the line. Try entering `2x`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo solid point; I'd used `ignore(1)` for the sake of example, but it'd be better to do `ignore(INT_MAX)` or something similar. Will edit code accordingly.

Comment: Make it `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` to be sure :-D

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wasn't even aware that was a thing, I've always been using `INT_MAX`. Learn something new every day!

Comment: It's the "_unspecified_" part of  `typedef /*unspecified*/ streamsize;` that makes it a little safer ... as if a user would ever go that nuts :-)

Answer (score 3):

The newline character is still in the buffer when you do `cin >> t` so the next line you read will be blank. When you mix formatted input (`>>`) and unformatted (`std::getline`) you often get in situations like this and you need to take measures when switching to unformatted input. Example remedy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skip the rest of the line

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        if(getline(cin, str))    // check that the getline actually succeeded
            cout << str << '\n';
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```