# Using getline to read but user need to use enter twice

Tags: c++, cin

To allow a multiple words user input I use `getline` and I flush the stream according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/8614416) with this code :

```
while(!everyoneAnswered()){
    string name;
    std::cout << "enter your name : ";
    if (getline(std::cin, name)) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // flush stream
        std::cout << "enter your age : ";
        int age;
        std::cin >> age;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        // stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is that now the user has to hit enter two times for the input to get accepted. I guess it's because `getline` consumes the first `\n`.

How can I avoid this, so that the user only hit enter once for the input to validate?

Here is an example of the result without the flush:

```
enter your name : foo
enter your age : 42
enter your name : enter your age : 69
--crashing because second name is empty--
```

Here is an example of the result **with** the flush :

```
enter your name : foo

enter your age : 42
enter your name : bar

enter your age : 69
```

Finally the flush without `\n` delimiter hangs on the first try waiting for `MAX_INT` characters entered.

I use `gcc` version 7.5.0 (`Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04`).

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are these two lines:

```
if (getline(std::cin, name)) {
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

The `getline` call includes the newline, so your `ignore` call will read the *next* line of input.

You need the `ignore` call after reading the `age` (with `>>`), but not after `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to also use `getline()` to read the age and parse it to an int. I don't know why mixing `getline()` and `operator>>` produces this behavior, though.

Comment: That's not the solution. That's a workaround. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction) is the solution. _"What you'll have to do is discard the new line yourself before `std::getline()` runs (but do it after the formatted extraction)"_ You have to discard it after the formatted read, not after the unformatted read.

Comment: Thanks, the other answer resolved the problem but your link gives a good explanation