# Clearing std::cin in C++

Tags: c++, cin

I have a console game where the player uses the keys <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, and <kbd>D</kbd> to move. I get the key input using the `getKeyState()` function in the `<windows.h>` lib.

However, when I prompt the player to play again using `std::cin`, all the keyboard inputs are shown, and the user has to delete all of the characters manually.

You could encounter the same problem if something like this happens:

```cpp
Sleep(10000)  // user types something here
char input;
std::cin << input;  // user sees what they typed here
```

Is it possible to clear this so the user does not see what they previously typed?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the keyboard inputs are shown and the user has to delete all the characters manually"? There is no output in the code posted. Please provide [mcve] of code that compiles and reproduces the problem, including example input and output.

Comment: Maybe you want [_getch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170). This is how we used to do it way back in the day. Before Windows, even.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen in the code that I supplied, let's say the user types "hello" during the time the program is sleeping. When the user is prompted for input on line 3, the "hello" that they typed will appear. I do not want the user to see what they typed before the std::cin.

Comment: @paddy thanks for your suggestion. Doing while (_kbhit()) { _getch(); } worked.

Comment: Using `std::cin` is not the ideal way to solve your problem. If you are using a console, then I recommend that you use the function [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput). You can use [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) with a console handle to wait for new input to be available.

Comment: @AlexanderJCS It should be `std::cin >> input;` instead of `std::cin << input;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flush the cin buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer)

Comment: @DavidFong thank you for your help. I was able to clear the input buffer by doing while (_kbhit()) { _getch(); }.