# I don't know how I can display on screen ONLY ONCE a message error

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReqAe.png)

Hello I have made a simple calculator with a switch sentence.
And when the operation is different than (+, -, /, *) it displays an error.

Weird thing is that when I type for example aa. it displays 2 times the error message.

I would like to know if there is a way to manage this.

I tried to create a boolean for this, like when you use semaphores in Java, and you put a semaphore acquired.
But obviously id

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it, like showing us a [mre].

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: It depends entirely on how you read input – and when thereby you provide `aa`. If you read single characters and parse manually you'll them need to remember if an error has already been shown (and maybe reset on reading a newline). Similarly if you read complete tokens at once, e.g. by using `std::cin.operator>>`, but you need to additionally clear error flags and [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/1312382) the invalid input.

Comment: My recommendation, though, is reading entire lines via [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), then you can just stop parsing at discovering invalid input and ignore the rest of the line.

Comment: The problem is not with output but with input. Before the validity check, add `cout << '|' << operacion << '|' << endl;` and see what you got.

Comment: Yet another recommendation: Replace all non-English identifiers with purely English ones – some day you *will* present your code to non-hispanophones, and if only here on SO. Non-English identifiers will force them to *guess* the meaning (admitted, in given case pretty simple, but that won't always be the case) making it much heavier to understand your code. Apart from such wild language mixture is pretty unaesthetic (admitted, too, personal opinion…).

Comment: Hi, quite hard to help you without a hint of what is the code (a picture is hard to be debugged)

Comment: When you figure this out, I've got a couple of compiler manufacturers you should talk to.

Comment: You've got to make some decisions here.  You can emit an error message, then set the input pointer to the next safe marker (many compilers do this), or you can keep parsing hoping that the remaining text is safe.

Comment: You can assign numbers to the errors and a variable name.  Use an error logger that will search a table of existing errors (and variables) so that the error is only emitted once.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are two possible problems in play here.

The first is if you give an invalid input for the operation. If you give two characters as input (like e.g. `aa`) then the first stream extraction will read the *first* of those, notice that it's invalid, and print the error message.

That will leave the second `a` still in the input buffer, to be read in the next iteration, so it all happens again.

---

The second problem is when you attempt to extract an integer, and you input an invalid value (like `aa`). That can't be extracted as an integer, so the input will just be left in the input buffer, while `0` will be written to the variable while the stream is set to a failed state.

When the loop then iterates, and you attempt to read the operation, it will fail because the stream is in a failed state. The operations value will be in an *indeterminate* state with an indeterminate values. And in C++, using an indeterminate value in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

---

The common solution is to read whole lines into a string, got example using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and then attempt to validate and parse this string.

For example for the operation, you could check to make sure that only one single character was entered, and then check that character.

For the numbers, you could use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the input string to an `int` value, with validation.